# wordDiff must return array of strings with word in s that are not in t, in the order they appear in s

Tags: c++, sequence, set-difference

```
using namespace std;
vector<string> wordDiff(string s, string t)
{
    istringstream parse_s(s);
    vector<string> words_s(istream_iterator<string>(parse_s), {});

    istringstream parse_t(t);
    vector<string> words_t(istream_iterator<string>(parse_t), {});

    sort(words_s.begin(), words_s.end());
    sort(words_t.begin(), words_t.end());

    vector<string> funk;
    set_difference(words_s.begin(), words_s.end(), 
                        words_t.begin(), words_t.end(),
                        back_inserter(ret));
    return funk;
}
```

so far i am able to get the array of strings with words in s that are not i  t with set_difference however i am unable to get the array in the order of s

Comment: Do you have complexity requirements? Your code works in `O(N log N + M log M)`, and takes additional O(N+M) memory.

Comment: If you are sorting vector s, haven't you tainted the meaning of what it's order is?

Comment: As @infixed already pointed out, you shouldn't sort `word_s`, if you want to keep the order.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is not to sort `words_s` (only `words_t`) and use `std::remove_if`:

```
  sort(words_t.begin(), words_t.end());

  auto it = std::remove_if( words_s.begin(), words_s.end(), [words_t]( const std::string &str ) {
      return std::find( words_t.begin(), words_t.end(), str ) != words_t.end() );
  } );
  words_s.erase( it, words_s.end() );
```

you may want consider to use `std::unordered_set` instead of sorted vector for `words_t`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to put all excluded words into a `std::unordered_set` instead of a `std::vector`.

Then you can use the set to check each word in your word list if it has to be excluded or not. This way, you no longer need to sort. All you need is a `copy_if` and a lambda.